# How to get distance in pixels of element inside of parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery

so I'm using Jquery and pure js to write small application, I have a element inside of a div parent.This Draggable element (ui widget) that can be moved around in div parent.I would like to get exact amount of pixels from the top and from the left.

This is what I mean:
[image]

I have following code right now, but with this code I can't get exact ammount of pixels from top and bottom,

```
$('#dragThis').draggable(
{
    drag: function(){
        var parentOffset =$(this).parent().offset(); 
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        var xPos = offset.left - parentOffset.left ;
        var yPos = offset.top - parentOffset.top  ;
        $('#posX').text('x: ' + xPos);
        $('#posY').text('y: ' + yPos);
    },
    containment: "#parentDiv"
});
```

Working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/8fbdf93m/

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also try `$(this).css('left')` or `$(this).css('top')`

updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8fbdf93m/4/

Answer (score 1):

Try [Jquery.Position](https://api.jquery.com/position/) method. It allows you to retrieve the current position of an element relative to the offset parent

Comment: Yes but this way I don't get px amount ,right? I did the same with pure js and amount of pixels doesn't match